# String to int rounding number on nodeJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string as numbers. And I want to transform string to int.

So my code like that:

```
const bigNumber = '6972173290701864962'
console.log(bigNumber)
//6972173290701864962         =====> last digits : *****1864962 

console.log(Number(bigNumber))
//6972173290701865000         =====> last digits : *****1865000
```

Why Im getting rounding number? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: Your value is larger than what can be accurately represented in JavaScript numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The number is greater than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Instead, cast a to a [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```js
const bigNumber = '6972173290701864962'
console.log('Number: '+Number(bigNumber))
console.log('BigInt: '+BigInt(bigNumber))
```

To remove the trailing `n`, simply call `toString()`:

```js
const bigNumber = '6972173290701864962'
console.log(BigInt(bigNumber).toString());
```

Comment: Thanks @Spectric. I made with BigInt(bigNumber). But Its added 'n' to last digit of the number. Why and What is the correct way for escape this 'n' case.

Comment: @akasaa Call `toString()`